# SQL transactions in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

So today the day has come where I need to write SQL transactions, and it's not going well, so far. I have two questions.

I need to do two things at once, execute a select statement and an update. I need to select the id, user and address and I need to update the same row by setting checked to 1.

Reading the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/start-transaction/) I was able to put the following SQL statement together.

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT @A:=id, user, address
 FROM addresses 
 WHERE checked = 0 
 AND user IS NOT NULL 
 ORDER BY id ASC 
 LIMIT 1; 
 UPDATE addresses 
 SET checked = 1 
 WHERE id = @A; 
 COMMIT;
```

But it's giving this error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
>       use near 'SELECT @A:=id FROM addresses WHERE checked = 0 AND user IS NOT NULL ' 
>       at line 2 in ... 
>       Stack trace: #0 ...: 
>       PDO->prepare('\r\n\t START TRANS...') #1 {main} thrown in ... on line 80

This is all the code:

```
<?php
// Database connection
$Sserver    = 'localhost';
$Susername  = 'root';
$Spassword  = '';
$Sdatabase  = 'db';
$Scharset   = 'utf8';

//Set up connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=$Sserver;dbname=$Sdatabase;charset=$Scharset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES  => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS       => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_CASE               => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
];
$dbcon = new PDO($dsn, $Susername, $Spassword, $opt);

$query ='    
     START TRANSACTION;
     SELECT @A:=id, user, address
     FROM addresses 
     WHERE checked = 0 
     AND user IS NOT NULL 
     ORDER BY id ASC 
     LIMIT 1; 
     UPDATE addresses 
     SET checked = 1 
     WHERE id = @A; 
     COMMIT;';

$query = $dbcon->prepare($query);
if(!$query->execute())
{
    //If query not successful.
    echo 'SQL ERROR: error in function ';
    die();
} 
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(empty($result['id']))

    echo '';
else
    echo $result['id'];

?>
```

So my first question is, what is wrong with my code? I will move this in the future to a Windows Server 2016 with Windows SQL, but for now I want it to work on my xampp instance running mariadb.

And my other question, what's the most efficient way of executing this query with my $dbcon PDO setup? I don't think I need a prepare statement...

**EDIT**

I still want to use the transaction method. Mark Baker pointed me in the right direction but my code is still not working. Now my code is this:

```
// Database connection
$Sserver    = 'localhost';
$Susername  = 'root';
$Spassword  = '';
$Sdatabase  = 'db';
$Scharset   = 'utf8';

//Seting up connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=$Sserver;dbname=$Sdatabase;charset=$Scharset";
$opt = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
];
$dbcon = new PDO($dsn, $Susername, $Spassword, $opt);

//SQL Transaction
$dbcon->beginTransaction();
$dbcon->exec('SELECT @A:=id, user, address
     FROM addresses 
     WHERE checked = 0 
     AND user IS NOT NULL 
     ORDER BY id ASC 
     LIMIT 1;');
$dbcon->exec('UPDATE addresses 
     SET checked = 1 
     WHERE id = @A;');
$dbcon->commit(); 
$result = $dbcon->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

But this will output

> Call to undefined method PDO::fetchAll()

But the first exec function returns 0 so something is wrong there. Can someone help me get this straight please?

Comment: Nope that doesn't work, I'll edit that

Comment: Use [PDO->beginTransaction()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), and the appropriate [PDO->rollBack()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) or [PDO->commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php), and separate PDO queries for your select and update .... and you don't really need separate select and update queries either, you could do it in a single query

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you very much! But in what situations is the rollback used? and do you happen to know, what if the db is busy on request? will it wait and handle the request when it's ready or will it fail the request?

Comment: You would use a rollback if the queries failed for any reason, a commit on success.... you don't even need a transaction for what you're doing; but if you were executing multiple related updates/inserts/deletes (e.g. insert order header record, insert line items for order, etc) for different tables, then transactions are appropriate

Comment: And it's always a good idea to get in the habit of using prepared statements for consistency; rather than sometimes using them, sometimes not

Comment: Please state the rest of the problem.  If you are doing nothing but setting a flag, you don't need the `SELECT`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging I found the solution myself. Here's how I did the SQL transaction with a SELECT and UPDATE statement, in PHP.

```
$dbcon = new PDO($dsn, $Susername, $Spassword, $opt);
$dbcon->beginTransaction();
$sql1 = 'SELECT @A:=id, user, address
     FROM addresses 
     WHERE checked = 0 
     AND user IS NOT NULL 
     ORDER BY id ASC 
     LIMIT 1
     FOR UPDATE;';
$sql2 = 'UPDATE addresses 
     SET checked = 1 
     WHERE id = @A;';   
$prep = $dbcon->prepare($sql1);
$prep->execute(); 
$prep2 = $dbcon->prepare($sql2);
$prep2->execute(); 
$dbcon->commit();
$result = $prep->fetch();
print_r($result);
```

Comment: No:  You need `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, else another connection can sneak in and grab the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just combine into 1 SQL statement instead of 2 ...

```
UPDATE addresses 
  SET checked = 1 
  WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM addresses
      WHERE checked = 0 AND user IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
  );
```

(oops, just saw that @Mark Baker already suggested this with "do it in a single query")

UPDATE:  Just learned this doesn't work in MariaDB/MySQL (sorry, I'm more of a Postgres/SQLite/Oracle/DB2 guy).  From googling the error message, here's a [workaround](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/) (you ain't the only one with this problem):

```
UPDATE addresses 
  SET checked = 1 
  WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT id FROM addresses
        WHERE checked = 0 AND user IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
    )
  );
```

Comment: I did suggest it, but you've clarified exactly what I meant :)

Comment: Yes I tried this before but when I execute this I get following error: General error: 1093 Table 'addresses' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data ... - and I couldn't fix it. + I need to output id, user, address

Comment: Depending on database, you might want to alias the two different references to addresses

Comment: Hmm, don't work in MariaDB.  I googled the error message and found a workaround for MariaDB/MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  addresses SET
        checked = 1,
        id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
    WHERE  checked = 0
      AND  user IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  id ASC
    LIMIT  1;
```

This formulation

- is atomic (no transaction needed),
- more efficient,
- provides the `id` via `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` -- if you needed @A for something else,
- avoids the bug (in most other attempts) caused by not using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`,
- might benefit from `INDEX(checked, id, user)`

Answer (score -1):

check your mariadb table engin

```
show table status from  translation_dic like '%your tables%';
```

and if you Engine MyISAM , not support translation
if you want translation change to InnoDB